# AWS Lambda function not receiving Records object from S3 bucket event trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an AWS bucket event attached to a Lambda function as a trigger.

Any time the bucket gets a new object, it should send an event object to a Lambda function that includes an array of records, like this:

```
{ "Records": 
  [ { "eventVersion": "2.1",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "eventTime": "2022-08-30T02:49:09.617Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": { "principalId": "***************" },
      "requestParameters": { "sourceIPAddress": "*********" },
      "responseElements": { "x-amz-request-id": "*************", "x-amz-id-2": "**************" },
      "s3": {
            "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
            "configurationId": "**********",
            "bucket": { "name": "my-bucket-name",
            "ownerIdentity": { "principalId": "**********" },
            "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name" },
            "object": {
                  "key": "my-object.wav",
                  "size": 295006,
                  "eTag": "******************",
                  "sequencer": "********************"
                  }
            }
  } ]
}
```

Instead I get this event object, which does not contain and array of records:

```
{
  callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop: [Getter/Setter],
  succeed: [Function (anonymous)],
  fail: [Function (anonymous)],
  done: [Function (anonymous)],
  functionVersion: '$LATEST',
  functionName: 'MY_NEW_FUNCTION_NAME',
  memoryLimitInMB: '128',
  logGroupName: '/aws/lambda/MY_NEW_FUNCTION_NAME',
  logStreamName: '2022/08/30/[$LATEST]****************',
  clientContext: undefined,
  identity: undefined,
  invokedFunctionArn: 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:993937220942:function:MY_NEW_FUNCTION_NAME',
  awsRequestId: 'f3e24964-13a6-45dc-88ff-************',
  getRemainingTimeInMillis: [Function: getRemainingTimeInMillis]
}
```

I need the array of records to get each s3 object's bucket and name.

What the heck am I looking at, and where is the event object I know and love?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out on my own.

I was looking at the context object, not the event object.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! If you don't think your question will assist future readers, feel free to delete the question.